# changed attributes not waving with Wordpress block

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a fairly simple block in a plugin, built using `npx @wordpress/create-block pn-DisplayBlocks`. Attributes, in block.json, are:

(code changed as per fixes below)

```
    "attributes": {
        "pid": {
            "type": "text",
            "default": "444"
        }
    }
```

save.js is:

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

export default function Save( {attributes} ) {

    console.log( "SAVING", attributes )
    return (
        <p { ...useBlockProps.save() }>
            { __( 'Pn Image – hello from the saved content! ' + attributes.pid, 'pn-image' ) }
        </p>
    );
}
```

and edit.js is:

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import './editor.scss';
import { __experimentalNumberControl as NumberControl } from '@wordpress/components';

export default function Edit( {attributes, setAttributes} ) {

    console.log( "pid", attributes.pid )
    return (
        <p { ...useBlockProps() }>
            { 
                __( 'Pn Image – hello from the editor! ' + attributes.pid, 'pn-image' ) 
            }
            <NumberControl
                label="PID"
                isShiftStepEnabled={ true }
                onChange={ value => { setAttributes( {pid: value})} }
                shiftStep={ 10 }
                value={ attributes.pid }
            />
        </p>

    );
}
```

NumberControl value updates pid and the block with the correct number value when changed, that all works fine, but if I preview the page I see the default value of pid showing, not the one I've just change it to. Same if I update the page to save it; console.log shows the new pid value but when reloaded into the edit page, pid reverts to the default value. Maybe I'm staring too hard but for the life of me I can't see what's wrong. Also, I'm fairly new to this so I may be doing something idiotic.

save & edit called from registerBlockType in index.js:

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';

import './style.scss';

import Edit from './edit';
import Save from './save';

registerBlockType( 'pn-displayblocks/pn-image', {
    edit: Edit,
    save: Save,
} );
```

Attributes in block.json:

```
{
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "pn-displayblocks/pn-image",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Pn Image",
    "category": "widgets",
    "icon": "smiley",
    "description": "Example block written with ESNext standard and JSX support – build step required.",
    "supports": {
        "html": false
    },
    "textdomain": "pn-displayblocks",
    "editorScript": "file:./build/index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./build/index.css",
    "style": "file:./build/style-index.css",

    "attributes": {
        "pid": {
            "type": "text",
            "default": "444"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not clear what's the relationship between `Edit` and `save`. Also `save` can't be named lower letter, because you output a component. Please show the lines where either `Edit` invokes `save`, or the other way around.

Comment: You're right, it's inconsistent but changing save to Save doesn't appear to help. I've added code to my op, hopefully to clarify

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to store your attributes in comments of block ?

In according with documentation [gutenberg](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/#value-source) :

```
The available source values are:
– (no value) – when no source is specified then data is stored in the block’s comment delimiter.
– attribute – data is stored in an HTML element attribute.
– text – data is stored in HTML text.
– html – data is stored in HTML. This is typically used by RichText.
– query – data is stored as an array of objects.
– meta – data is stored in post meta (deprecated)
```

Can you try with ?

```json
 "pid": {
    "type": "text",
    "default": "444"
  }
```

Comment: This partially fixes. Refreshing the page editor after saving now shows up the new, changed value from the NumberControl but when previewed, attributes.pid is showing in the page as undefined.

Comment: OK. I have it. export default function Save( attributes ) should be export default function Save( {attributes} )

Comment: Nice, maybe you can edit your post with the solution